# Q: Offline Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I'm writing a program that can deploy to Kubernetes.
The main problem that I'm facing is "Offline mode" when I disconnect the computer from the router Kubernetes stops working because it needs the default route in the network interfaces.

Does anyone know how to set up Kubernetes so it will work without the default network interface?

I tried Minikube and MicroK8S without success.

Answer (score 1):

Few Kubernetes installers support air-gapped installation and doing it yourself is way out of scope for a new user. If this is for work, you'll want to talk to some of the major commercial distros (OpenShift I'm pretty sure has an air-gap installer, probably also Tanzu) but for new-user home use you should consider this not an option.

Comment: thanks for the replay, the air-gap word will help me to find something useful on google I hope :)